# Prevent Duplicate Events from Importing via The Events Calendar WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Backstory: we're using the Events Aggregator add-on plugin from The Events Calendar to import events via a cron job. Problem is, the plugin code only checks against the UID-- and the feed provider is crap, and changes out that "UNIQUE" ID around once per day. So we're getting duplicate events imported like crazy.

I figured I could address this by checking not only against the UID, but also the post title, the event start date, and the event end date. It was not nearly as easy as I thought it would be, and I'll document why below.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1: finding the right hook

The Events Calendar doesn't have many good actions/filters for outside developers: they're mostly for internal use. They were kind enough to suggest I try `save_post`.

The only problem with that is that I couldn't figure out how to access the post meta for the event start or end date in the middle of a `save_post` hook: neither The Event Calendar's functions nor `get_post_meta` worked.

So, I hooked into `updated_post_meta` and `added_post_meta` instead, like this:

```php
function check_for_duplicate_event_when_meta_updated( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    // Make sure we are handling just the meta field we are interested in.
    if ( $meta_key !== '_EventEndDate' ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'tribe_events' ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( trim( $meta_value ) == '' ) {
        return false;
    }

    clear_out_potential_duplicate_events( $post_id );
}

add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'check_for_duplicate_event_when_meta_updated', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'check_for_duplicate_event_when_meta_updated', 10, 4 );
```

### Problem 2: Getting the Title to Match

The feed provider also included some en dashes in the feed titles, like this:

"Something - Is - Spaced Apart - A Lot"

I used `get_the_title()` so I could compare the post title of the incoming post to what was already in the database. The only problem was, `get_the_title()` converted those dash characters to HTML entities, like this:

"Something – Is – Spaced Apart – A Lot"

No big deal though, just convert them back to dash characters with `html_entity_decode`, right? WRONG. This is what it gave me when I converted the string back:

"Something — Is — Spaced Apart — A Lot"

It converted my dang en dashes to em dashes! Now my SQL query couldn't work.

I found the solution though, is to turn off the `wp_texturize` filter temporarily. Here's the second half of the solution:

```php
function clear_out_potential_duplicate_events( $post_id, $post = null, $update = false ) {

    if ( DOING_CRON === false ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( $update === true ) {
        return false;
    }

    global $wpdb;

    $wptexturize = remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );

    $title_check = get_the_title( $post_id );

    if ( $wptexturize ) {
        add_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
    }

    $start_date_check = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_EventStartDate', true );
    $end_date_check = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_EventEndDate', true );

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM `wp_posts` JOIN `wp_postmeta` ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_value = '$start_date_check' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '$end_date_check' AND wp_posts.post_title = '$title_check'" );

    if ( ! empty( $results ) ) {
        wp_delete_post( $post_id );
    }
}
```

### Tying Everything Together

The last part, the SQL query is pretty simple: it searches the database to see if something like the post that is being imported already exists. If the query returns an ID in the results array, then the event most likely already exists, and the event that is in the process of being imported is deleted instead.

<sub>*(Hopefully this saves somebody else a lot of time and frustration.)*</sub>